# Are OpenJDK and non-Windows systems vulnerable to the Sept. 25th 2012 Java vulnerability?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, java

I have heard of [this vulnerability](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2012/Sep/170), but although it was announced on the Full Disclosure list, it does not provide any details (other than a severity assessment). Does anyone have more info than me, and is able to tell whether non-Oracle JREs (OpenJDK's, for instance) and non-Windows systems are vulnerable to it?

Answer (score 2):

It's been less than 24 hours, and it doesn't seem to have a CVE entry yet, so it's difficult to say. The details are pretty sparse.

All I can give you is my best guess:

- Any initial exploits will work on Oracle Java SE only.
- A variant of the vulnerability *may* affect OpenJDK, but it's unlikely to have the exact same problem. This is because it's an entirely different codebase. We *may* see problems later on with OpenJDK though.
- It'll be cross-platform, since the constraint violation is in the JVM, not in anything Windows-specific. It may even work on non-x86 machines, e.g. ARM / PPC.